# Large scale naïve Bayes classifier with top-k output

Tags: nlp, machine-learning, bayesian, classification

I need a library for naïve Bayes large scale, with millions of training examples and +100k binary features. It must be an online version (updatable after training). I also need top-k output, that is multiple classifications for a single instance. Accuracy is not very important.

The purpose is an automatic text categorization application.

Any suggestions for a good library is very appreciated.

EDIT: The library should preferably be in Java.

Comment: I can't believe I forgot that, but preferably Java. But if there are no other alternatives, anything will do.

Comment: I don't know if it has the exact specs you're looking for, but have you checked out [Weka](http://weka.sourceforge.net/manuals/weka.bn.pdf) at all?

Comment: @jonsca: the PDF you link to describes Bayes networks, not naïve Bayes.

Comment: @larsmans Thank you, regrettably I don't know quite enough about this specific field.

Comment: @jonsca Yes, I have used Weka before. It won't do for this project I'm afraid. It simply is not as scalable as I would want.

Comment: @Rasmus Ah, okay. It was the first thing I thought of when you said Java.  I have done some pattern recognition in the past, but as I said to @larsmans, I don't have all the specifics anymore.  Sounds like a cool project, hopefully that `Vowpal Wabbit` package can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a learning algorithm other than naïve Bayes is also acceptable, then check out [Vowpal Wabbit](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit) (C++), which has the reputation of being one of the best scalable text classification algorithms (online stochastic gradient descent + LDA). I'm not sure if it does top-K output.

Comment: The only reason for naïve Bayes is that it works well with binary dependent features.I will ask around on the Vowpal Wabbit lists and see if it can do top-K output.

Comment: @Rasmus: I don't know what you mean by "binary dependent features", but naïve Bayes is designed to work (only) with mutually *independent* features.

Comment: Binary means on/off, meaning it only takes two values

See for example for naïve Bayes on _dependent_ features: http://www.mendeley.com/research/optimality-nave-bayes-dependent-binary-features-4/# or 
http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~isbell/classes/reading/papers/Rish.pdf